# How to identify proxy protocol from IP and Port?

Tags: proxy

Say I have a list of proxies - I pull out of one of these proxies. It's nothing but `ip` and `port`. From a programming level, you need to know the protocol to use such as `socks5, socks5h, http, https...` etc etc. Is there a way to retrieve what kind of protocol a proxy uses from the information given?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/633639/detecting-whether-a-proxy-is-http-or-socks

Answer (score -2):

[image]

1. Your proxy server identify the port number for example 6080,9180,etc so you can easily identify the proxy server.
2. Your id address also private or public you can use 'proxy server ip address' that automatically create a virtual proxy network. 
   Example: Your private ip address is `172.16.10.158` you can use proxy server, your ip address will be `136.56.89.210`. You can use public ip ex `125.124.85.69` change in to `179.68.36.49`.

Comment: The sentences in your answer make no sense, and this in no way attempts to answer the OP's question.